# С: Как реализовать вывод вещественных чисел без незначащих нулей?

Tags: c, вывод, double, printf, обработка-данных

Функция выводит массив вещественных чисел. Но при это выводятся незначащие нули.

Можно ли как-то по-простому их срезать?

Например, есть

```
2.00000 0.00000 421.12340 5.12909
```

Нужно, чтобы было:

```
2. 0. 421.1234 5.12909
```

Comment: Если нужно по-простому, то вроде бы нельзя. А вот написать собственную версию вывода чисел с плавающей запятой очень даже можно. Кое-какие костыли на этот счёт обсуждались здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто, то что-то в таком духе

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ cat t.c && gcc t.c && echo "===== result =====" && ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
fz (double f, char *s)
{
  sprintf(s, "%f", f);
  char *p = strrchr(s, '0');

  if (p && !p[1])
    while (*p == '0')
      *p-- = 0;

  return s;
}


int main()
{
  double f = 1.203;

  printf("%f\n", f);

  char s[100];
  printf("%s\n", fz(f, s));
  printf("%s %s %s %s\n",
     fz(2.0, s), fz(0.0, s + 20), fz(421.1234, s + 40), fz(5.12909, s + 60));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
===== result =====
1.203000
1.203
2. 0. 421.1234 5.12909
End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```